# String won't appear on one line in python

Tags: python-3.x

I need to print a line from a a novel and then alphabetize the separate words contained in that line.  I have done that but the line and then the alphabetized words are supposed to print on one line each.  My code does not print on 2 lines.  My output is 6 lines.

```
    def problem4_1(wordlist):
    """ Takes a word list prints it, sorts it, and prints the sorted list """

    firstline = ["Happy", "families", "are", "all", "alike;", "every",
    "unhappy", "family", "is", "unhappy", "in", "its", "own",
    "way.", "Leo Tolstoy", "Anna Karenina"]

     print(firstline, end='\n')
     firstline.sort(key=str.lower)
     print(firstline, end='\n')
```

Comment: Have you tried clicking and dragging to make your window wider, so two lines will actually fit in the display without having to wrap around the edges?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.   That's not the problem, though.  I keep getting errors from the autograder and I know the problem is the number of lines in the output.  Tha

Comment: What exactly is you question? You code does print 2 lines. It is just to long for your IDE to properly show you. If you had a wider screen you would see only lines.

Comment: Thanks Green Cloak Guy and Andreas.  I guess there is a different problem with the autograder.

Answer (score 1):

You could make a copy of `firstline` and then, can print both the outputs in the same line. Like this:

```
firstline = ["Happy", "families", "are", "all", "alike;", "every",
"unhappy", "family", "is", "unhappy", "in", "its", "own",
"way.", "Leo Tolstoy", "Anna Karenina"]

firstline2 = firstline
firstline2.sort(key=str.lower)

print(firstline,firstline2)
```

Comment: Noob Geek.  I love your solution. It's so compact.  There is one problem, though, and that is that the output for both "firstline" and "firstline2" are both the alphabetized list of words.  "Firstline" is not printing out the quote from the book as it appears above but "firstline2" does what it is supposed to.

Comment: Then use `Firstline.sort()` before printng it.

Comment: Thanks so much!  I really appreciate it.

Comment: If you like my answer, Feel free to vote and/or accept it. Thanks